# Sub project creation under one main project in JIRA

Tags: jira, project-management, jira-agile

I have my one project which is getting expanded in different countries. I want to create one single project and sub project for different country in JIRA to track separately the progress

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple boards in Jira that all point to the same project. All you need is some way of differentiating between them.

For example you could have a custom field that indicated the target country for an issue.

The steps you would take are as follows:

- Create the project
- [Add the custom field to the issues in that project](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/adding-custom-fields-1047552713.html)
- [Create several filters, with each one selecting all the issues for a given country in your custom field](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-work-management/docs/save-your-search-as-a-filter/)
- [Create a board for each filter](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/create-a-board/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements: if you do not want each sub-project visibility to other sub-project members, you should create a new project for every subproject and use either filters and/or dashboards to monitor them.

If visibility is not a problem, You might consider using components for each sub-project.